# python: list of matrices to numpy array?

Tags: python, numpy, matrix

I've got a list containing numpy matrices. Anyway that I could turn the whole thing into a nice clean numpy array?

From:

```
[matrix([[1]]), matrix([[ 1.99387871]]), matrix([[ 2.53564618]]), matrix([[ 4.39125807]]), matrix([[ 4.246309]]), matrix([[ 5.21571607]]), matrix([[ 6.17408811]]), matrix([[ 4.75146571]]), matrix([[ 6.19319742]]), matrix([[ 6.1277607]]), matrix([[ 7.43821216]])]
```

To:

```
[[1 1.99387871 2.53564618 4.39125807 4.246309 5.21571607 6.17408811 4.75146571 6.19319742 6.1277607 7.43821216]]
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
b = np.asarray(a, dtype=float)
#to get the same shape do.
b = b.reshape(-1, len(b)) 
#to just get one dimmension do. 
b = np.asarray(a, dtype=float).reshape(len(a))
```

Comment: Maybe add `.reshape(-1, len(a))` if the OP cares about the shape.

Comment: Also, I don't think you want the `dtype=float`. Without it, you preserve the dtype of the individual matrices—or, if they're different, as in the OP's example, the coerced union of the types. That's probably better than forcing `float` even if there were, say, `float128` or `complex128` values in the matrices.

Comment: @abarnert True, for the general case forcing float is not a good solution, but setting the dtype when you know what it is, usually a good idea. Sometimes numpy isn't smart enough to figure them out and will just set it as a generic object. which can cause problems.