# Norm of moving window submatrix

Tags: python, matrix, convolution

I try to create a function for performing a convolution between a matrix and a filter. I managed to do the basic operations, but I stumbled on calculating the norm of the sliced matrix (the submatrix of the main matrix), corresponding to each position in the output.

The code is this:

```
def convol2d(matrix, kernel):
    # matrix - input matrix indexed (v, w)
    # kernel - filtre indexed (s, t),
    # h -output indexed (x, y),
    # The output size is calculated by adding smid, tmid to each side of the dimensions of the input image.
    norm_filter = np.linalg.norm(kernel) # The norm of the filter

    vmax = matrix.shape[0]
    wmax = matrix.shape[1]
    smax = kernel.shape[0]
    tmax = kernel.shape[1]
    smid = smax // 2
    tmid = tmax // 2
    xmax = vmax + 2 * smid
    ymax = wmax + 2 * tmid
    window_list = [] # Initialized an empty list for storing the submatrix

    print vmax
    print xmax

    h = np.zeros([xmax, ymax], dtype=np.float)

    for x in range(xmax):
        for y in range(ymax):
            s_from = max(smid - x, -smid)
            s_to = min((xmax - x) - smid, smid + 1)
            t_from = max(tmid - y, -tmid)
            t_to = min((ymax - y) - tmid, tmid + 1)
            value = 0
            for s in range(s_from, s_to):
                for t in range(t_from, t_to):
                    v = x - smid + s
                    w = y - tmid + t
                    print matrix[v, w]
                    value += kernel[smid - s, tmid - t] * matrix[v, w]

                    # This does not work
                    window_list.append(matrix[v,w])
                    norm_window = np.linalg.norm(window_list) 

            h[x, y] = value / norm_filter * norm_window
    return h
```

For example, my input matrix is `A(v, w)`, I want that my output values in the output matrix `h (x,y)`, be calculated as:

```
h(x,y) = value/ (norm_of_filer * norm_of_sumbatrix)
```

Thanks for any help!

Edit: Following the suggestions, I modified like this:

I modified like this, but I only get the first row appended, and used in calculation and not the entire submatrix.

```
       `for s in range(s_from, s_to):
             for t in range(t_from, t_to):
                    v = x - smid + s
                    w = y - tmid + t
                    value += kernel[smid - s, tmid - t] * matrix[v, w]
                    window_list.append(matrix[v,w])
             window_array = np.asarray(window_list, dtype=float)
        window_list = []
        norm_window = np.linalg.norm(window_array)
        h[x, y] = value / norm_filter * norm_window`
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The input of np.linalg.norm is supposed to be an "Input array."  Try converting the list of matrices to an array. ([python: list of matrices to numpy array?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20749843/python-list-of-matrices-to-numpy-array))

Also, maybe move the norm_window line out of the loop, since you only later use it as evaluated at the last step, with everything in it.  In fact, wait 'til the loop is done, convert the finished list to an array (so it's only done once) and evaluate norm_window on that.

Comment: I edited my question, with the code sample I tried. It only uses the first row in calculation.

Comment: Try taking window_array = np.asarray out of the s-loop as well.  Have you looked at the structure of window_list and window_array?  You may need to reshape the array. Or you could set up an empty array of the appropriate dimensions and put each value into its proper spot (via indices) as you loop.  Hope that makes sense.

Comment: This worked. Sorry for my late reply and thank you for the answer! :)